# Git and GitHub concepts: Reviewing updated pull requests locally

Tags: git, github, version-control, upstream-branch

I follow the generic OSS structure:

1. the OSS' remote repository hosted on GitHub
2. a fork of the OSS remote repository to my own remote repository
3. a clone of the fork on my remote repository to create a local repository

Thus, a contributor would create a new branch locally, push the changes to his/her remote repository, and then open a pull request to the OSS' remote repository.

This has been working well. However, the main issue comes when I try to review another contributor's pull request by fiddling with it **locally**.

So I have fetched a pull request made to the OSS' remote repository using this command:

`git fetch upstream pull/<PR#>/head:<branchName>`

followed by `git checkout <branchName>`

and it was successful. I played around with the PR, and reviewed it on GitHub. Then, the contributor updated the PR by pushing new commits to their branch (on their remote repo), which was automatically reflected in the PR.

Now, I want to be able to get the updates locally so that I can try the changes again. I understand that my copy of the PR branch does not track the remote branch by default, so I tried to set it to track the PR:

`git branch --set-upstream upstream/pull/<PR#>/head:<branchName>`

like how I have done when I first fetched the branch. However, I got the response that

> error: the requested upstream branch 'pull//head:' does not exist

I tried again with:

`git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/pull/<PR#>/head:<branchName>`

which also failed with the same error.

Then, I thought, is it because a PR is like a 'reflection' of the branch on someone's remote repository, so if I want to track an upstream branch I should track from the person's remote repository?

So I added the contributors' remote repository as a remote, and tried again:

`git branch --set-upstream-to <newRemote> <branchName>`

and I still faced the same error.

I did some Googling, and I found [this](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247), but I do not want to get **all** the pull requests. I also found links like [this one](https://bocoup.com/blog/git-workflow-walkthrough-reviewing-pull-requests-local) but nope, not the help that I need there.

Can anyone point out what is wrong with the way that I am doing things now?  Thanks!

Edit: Is there an easier way to do things aside from what has been proposed by Marina Liu - MSFT below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of below options to update the PR in local repo.

#### Option 1: delete the local source branch and recreate to get the update

As you use the commands to get the source branch of the PR locally:

```
git fetch upstream pull/<PR#>/head:<branchName>
git checkout <branchname>
```

If the PR is updated (new commits are pushed to the fork repo), you can delete and recreate by:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D <branchname>
git fetch upstream pull/<PR#>/head:<branchName>
git checkout <branchname>
```

#### Option 2: add the fork repo as a remote for your local repo

You can add the fork repo as a remote for your local repo by

```
git remote add fork1 <URL for the fork repo> -f
```

Then you can create a local branch for the PR source branch by

```
git checkout -b <branchname> fork1/<branchname>
```

If the PR has been updated, you just need to execute below commands to get the update:

```
git fetch fork1
git checkout <branchname> #If HEAD is not on the <branchname>
git reset --hard fork1/<branchname>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Interestingly both sound like quite a hassle - imagine if I have to review many different contributor's PRs, some of whom may only open one PR ever, then I would have to keep updating my remotes :( but great suggestions nevertheless!

Comment: You just need to update only one remote which you want to update as the command `git fetch fork1` (or use `git fetch fork1 <branchname>` to update only one remote branch).

Comment: By fork repo, do you mean the original OSS repo?

Comment: No, the fork repo means the fork of OSS repo.

Comment: but...but...I already have it as a remote (`origin`) that is usually created by default when I clone the fork repository...Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Since you are the approver (personal who has permission to commit and push to OSS repo) for the PR to merge into OSS repo, I will suggest you clone the OSS repo (instead of the fork repo), and then add the fork repo as a remote for your local OSS repo.

Comment: Any way,  if you still want to treat the fork repo as origin remote (clone from the fork repo), the option2 in my answer still suitable. Just replace `fork1` with `origin`.

Comment: you mean `git reset --hard origin/<branchName>` ? I don't have the branch in my remote repository because I do not intend to modify the branch, just to test it.

Comment: The purpose of the command `git reset --hard remotename/branchname` is to update the local `<branchname>` same as the fork repo is. It just make change for the local `<branchname>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem—or at least the first one—here is that you cannot use an upstream to refer to a GitHub pull request reference.

In Git, an *upstream* on a branch consists of two parts:

- The name of a remote, such as `origin`
- The name of a *branch* on that remote, such as `master`

Git puts these two together to get `refs/heads/master`—this is the name *on the remote*—then runs this string through the `fetch` setting(s) for the remote.  The standard `fetch` setting for the remote named `origin` is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, so if the upstream is currently set to the pair <`origin`, `master`>, the name that Git looks up in *your own* repository is `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which is your remote-tracking name for their `master`.

Note the assumption in here that the name *on the remote* begins with `refs/heads/`.

The actual name of a pull reference on GitHub begins with `refs/pull/`, not `refs/heads/`, so that the full name of the commit you want for pull request #123 is `refs/pull/123/head`.  *There is no way to spell this that starts with `refs/heads/`* because this is not a *branch* name.

Now, you can—as suggested in [your first link](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247)—*add* an extra `fetch` setting:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

which causes their `refs/pull/123/head` to associate with your `refs/remotes/origin/pr/123`.  Depending on your particular Git version, *some* of this *sometimes* or even *mostly* works.  Some Git versions get rather confused at times.  If you try it and it works for you, that's great, just be prepared to clean up a bit of a mess if you upgrade or downgrade Git versions for some reason.

The [aliases](https://gist.github.com/gnarf/5406589) found via [your second link](https://bocoup.com/blog/git-workflow-walkthrough-reviewing-pull-requests-local) are better.  These fetch from one specific pull request, creating a local branch name (or overwriting it if it already exists—this is a bit dangerous but as long as you don't name your own branches `pr/integer` you will be fine).  You could improve them, writing a real `git-pr` script that creates a local branch—be sure to use the full name format, `refs/heads/pr/number`, to guarantee correctness—and sets some additional information so that, when you are on that branch, `git pr` updates the branch automatically.

(If I get some spare time, I might write my own script, because this would be pretty handy.)

Comment: Looking forward to the day you create a script for this. Right now I think I may lack the ability to write such a script :/